# Git command produce strange result

Tags: git

What could be the reason in my project for causing the following behaviour:

```
git fetch origin test
From github.unil.ch:gr-ci-gsg/sylvia
* branch                  test       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

`git checkout test`

=> Nothing happens, no error message, no branch change, this only happens with the branch named 'test'

On a fresh directory, this is working fine, there is something in the project that is causing this behaviour.

```
git --version --build-options
git version 2.19.0.windows.1
cpu: x86_64
built from commit: d96bb8bc6c636a8869140e860e72e7bdf64bd790
sizeof-long: 4
sizeof-size_t: 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git fetch` does not create branches.  At most, it creates or updates a *remote-tracking name*, such as `origin/test`.  Hence, if you did not have a branch named `test` before, you still do not have a branch named `test` afterwards.

If you now run `git checkout test`, Git looks around for a branch named `test` and does not find one.  Before giving up and saying "I have no idea what you mean", Git tries some alternatives.  One alternative would be to check for the *remote-tracking name* `origin/test`, and if it exists, to *create* a (local) branch named `test` using the remote-tracking name.  However, another alternative is to check for a *file* named `test`, and if it exists, re-extract it from the *current* branch.

My deductive powers tell me that you have a file named `test` and that Git is therefore doing the latter.

You can tell Git: *please create branch test based on `origin/test`* in several ways.  The simplest at this point is probably:

```
git checkout --track origin/test
```

assuming that your `git fetch` has created `origin/test` (with Git version 2.19, I think it probably has, but to make sure it does, just run `git fetch origin` with no additional arguments at all, so as to fetch and create or update the remote-tracking names for *all* of `origin`'s branches).